# Centos ssh can connect,but sftp can't connect

Tags: centos, ssh, sftp

I tried to connect my server with SFTP, but the connection failed.

My SSH can connect to the server.

When I change the ssh port back to 22, sftp can connect.

### this is client log

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/config        
debug1: /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for fiber
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22235.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/id_rsa type 0      
debug1: identity file /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 
debug1: Authenticating to xx.xx.xx.xx:22235 as 'yesion'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:i6dFte6Qbej2zrNoB0dfjGWE6aAMExv1aE8NG9JQx/E
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg explicit        
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg explicit     
debug1: Server accepts key: /c/Users/yesio/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xx.xx.xx.xx ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22235).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer
Connection closed
```

### this is my server log

```
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2804]: debug1: Forked child 2809.
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: rexec start in 7 out 7 newsock 7 pipe 9 sock 10
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 5, 5
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: Connection from xx.xx.xx.xx port 7387 on xx.xx.xx.xx port 22235
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.3
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: ssh_selinux_change_context: setting context from 'system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' to 'system_u:system_r:sshd_net_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]      
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]       
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth] 
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: userauth-request for user yesion service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "yesion"
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "xx.xx.xx.xx"
May 17 15:44:45 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: userauth-request for user yesion service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg [preauth]
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: trying public key file /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: fd 11 clearing O_NONBLOCK
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: matching key found: RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: Accepted key RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg found at /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: Postponed publickey for yesion from xx.xx.xx.xx port 7387 ssh2 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: userauth-request for user yesion service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: trying public key file /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: fd 11 clearing O_NONBLOCK
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: matching key found: RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: Accepted key RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg found at /home/yesion/.ssh/authorized_keys:3
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: do_pam_account: called
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: Accepted publickey for yesion from xx.xx.xx.xx port 7387 ssh2: RSA SHA256:ZCv3gRTiBBRt4yLSUVnk16NCDHp/FB6cMGPvFbUaytg
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: yesion has been authenticated by privileged process        
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options [preauth]
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 2
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: SELinux support enabled
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
May 17 15:44:46 fiber systemd[2813]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user yesion by (uid=0)
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user yesion by (uid=0)
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: User child is on pid 2823
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1000/1000
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: ssh_packet_set_postauth: called
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: active: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding  
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: server_init_dispatch
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 2097152 max 32768
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: input_session_request
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: session_new: session 0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: session_open: channel 0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0      
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request subsystem reply 1
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req subsystem
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: subsystem: exec() /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2823]: Starting session: subsystem 'sftp' for yesion from xx.xx.xx.xx port 7387 id 0
May 17 15:44:46 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: session_new: session 0
May 17 15:45:06 fiber sshd[2823]: Read error from remote host xx.xx.xx.xx port 7387: Connection reset by peer
May 17 15:45:06 fiber sshd[2823]: debug1: do_cleanup
May 17 15:45:06 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: do_cleanup
May 17 15:45:06 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
May 17 15:45:06 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: PAM: closing session
May 17 15:45:06 fiber sshd[2809]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user yesion
May 17 15:45:06 fiber sshd[2809]: debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

My `sshd_config` is

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
Port 22235
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# This system is following system-wide crypto policy. The changes to
# crypto properties (Ciphers, MACs, ...) will not have any effect here.
# They will be overridden by command-line options passed to the server
# on command line.
# Please, check manual pages for update-crypto-policies(8) and sshd_config(5).      

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel DEBUG

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes

# It is recommended to use pam_motd in /etc/pam.d/sshd instead of PrintMotd,
# as it is more configurable and versatile than the built-in version.
PrintMotd no

#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the commands you used and the results and/or error messages. The debug is good but it's best to be able to see the whole `sftp` session

Comment: `sftp` section from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on server would be of help too.

Comment: It's most likely an authenication problem. I'm using ssh keys only and I'm not trying to connect as root, so when I use "sftp -v" part of the output states "SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received", and "Authenticated to host ([x.x.x.x]:22)." Also, check the ./etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny files.

Comment: @roaima I updated my error message

Comment: comment this line `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` and add this line [`Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`](https://serverfault.com/a/660325/482932) and then reload the sshd_config and try again to see if you can connect. if it worked, I will convert it to answer

Comment: Still can't connect

Comment: How do you connect? what is your commad? show in yoir question and update the debug logs for that too.

Comment: I tried to connect, but the result is the same, the log of output is almost the same.

Comment: **It should not be the same!!** please add the exact command you are running to connect on sftp and update the debug logs after the comment I said above to change; add debug log of this `ssh -p port# user@remoteHost -vvv`; this line is saying something is wrong with sftp Subsystem `... sshd[2823]: Read error from remote host xx.xx.xx.xx port 7387: Connection reset by peer`; please also add the debug logs for when you are trying to connect over port 22 (or you can compare where those two has differences)? do the server has access on port 7387 to the client that initiated the sftp connection?